# Using custom vue directive with inertia js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, tailwind-css, inertiajs

I'm creating a laravel app with Inertia.js and Vue 3. I'd like to add a custom vue directive I made in another project (that didn't use Inertia). To do so, I added this in my app.js:

```
app.directive('uppercase',{
    updated(el){
        el.value = el.value.toUpperCase()
    }
});
```

However, as the app is initialised like this, I cannot add the same.

```
const app = createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy)
            .mount(el);
    },
    directive:{
        uppercase:{
            updated(el){
                el.value = el.value.toUpperCase()
            } 
        }
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#4B5563',
    },
});
```

Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the below steps to create custom directive

- Create a new file called `directives.js` in your Vue application's directory.
- In this file, define your custom directive using Vue.directive method.

```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.directive('custom-directive', {
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
  },
  update: function (el, binding, vnode) {
  },
  unbind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
  }
})
```

- Include `directives.js` in `app.js`

Comment: Thanks, but importing Vue doens't work. Throwing:


"Vue" is not exported by "node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js"